# Debian Buster: linux-image-amd64 kept back

Tags: linux, debian, apt

Perhaps a simple question, perhaps a stupid question, but I can't find an answer...

Whenever I do

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

I get

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-image-amd64
```

Sooooo, what exactly is happening here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Sooooo, what exactly is happening here?

The `apt-get upgrade` does not add new packages. The `linux-image-amd64` is a meta package that often depends on installing a **new** package that is the newest version of the kernel.

A new package is used whenever the ABI changes, this can be very important for anyone with any locally compiled modules, that aren't managed by DKMS or something.

Ref: https://wiki.debian.org/DebianKernelABIChanges

> Occasionally, and often due to a security issue, a change is accepted into a kernel package that changes its ABI. **The ABI change is represented by a change in the ABI version portion of the linux-image package name**.

Anyway, if you want to upgrade to the latest kernel use `apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Comment: kernel packages will only be upgraded with dist-upgrade

Comment: @djdomi that isn't entirely true. If a kernel update doesn't change the ABI then it will not have a new package name, and a `apt-get upgrade` will work.

Comment: I just did an apt-get dist-upgrade. I'm guessing I need to restart the server now so it loads the new kernel? Anything else I need to do before rebooting? I'm asking because I can remember with an older version of Debian, if I simply installed a new version of the kernel and restarted the server, my server would basicallybe dead because problems with grub prevented it from rebooting.

Comment: Generally you can just reboot and shouldn't have to do anything else. It is possible things could be broken with the bootloader.

Comment: `dist-upgrade` does much more than that and shouldn't be ran as-is on a stable system. @Zippy1970 the complete answer you couldn't find is here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/601/the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-why-and-how-do-i-solve-it/602#602

Comment: @SylvainB I am mostly of the opinion that running `apt-get dist-upgrade` is fine 99% of the time.  Assuming you a) stick to officially supported repos only b) actually read and understand the list of changes before confirming. You mostly won't run into problems. Also like any good sysadmin you have your backups, and dev systems that you will have tested your dist-upgrade on first.

Answer (score 4):

I'm just copying the relevant parts of [this complete answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/601/the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-why-and-how-do-i-solve-it/602#602), go check it out!:

Sooooo, what exactly is happening here?

> If the dependencies have changed on one of the packages you have installed so that a new package must be installed to perform the upgrade then that will be listed as "kept-back".

How to install those packages properly:

> sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade

Answer (score 0):

This makes sense:

```
The apt-get upgrade does not add new packages.
```

Now, I do not know the reason for the following observation:

This does not happen by running `apt upgrade`; it only happens with `apt-get upgrade`".

I've read that it's safer to run `apt-get install linux-image-amd64` instead of `dist-upgrade`. For those packages that remain in a *kept-back* state. Some people take the `dist-upgrade` as a "more aggressive or risky" solution.

Apparently, in some sense, `apt` manages and marks packages differently than `apt-get` does. What I haven't investigated yet.

Greetings